# commandargument for sql dataset buttonfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding

I have a sql dataset table which has two buttonfields (upvote and downvote). I am trying to add a commandArgument to these two buttonfields which links up to the sql data value compName (see code below) but I keep getting the following error:

"Error  6   Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not have a DataBinding event."

Here is my C# code to build the table:

```
 protected void searchTheDB()
{
    string s = "SELECT compName As 'Company/Organization Name', btcAddr As 'Bitcoin Address', Premium_User as 'Premium User'," + 
    "upvote as 'Upvotes',downvote As 'Downvotes' FROM clientDataTable WHERE compName LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";

    try
    {
        SqlConnection forSearch = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter search = new SqlDataAdapter(s, forSearch);
        DataSet dB = new DataSet();
        search.Fill(dB);
        searchGridView.DataSource = dB;
        searchGridView.DataBind();
        searchBox.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    catch (SqlException exp)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sorry, the website is experiencing difficulties, please try again, error: ", exp);
    }
}
```

and here is the Asp.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="searchGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="10" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="161px" Width="935px" CellSpacing="5" HorizontalAlign="Justify" BorderStyle="Solid" OnRowCommand="searchGridView_RowCommand">
                     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button"  CommandName="Upvote" Text="Upvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>'/>
                         <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Downvote" Text="Downvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>'/>
                     </Columns>

                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                     <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                 </asp:GridView>
```

the issue is on the buttonfield commandArguments

```
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button"  CommandName="Upvote" Text="Upvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>'/>
                         <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Downvote" Text="Downvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>'/>
                     </Columns>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `asp:ButtonField` doesn't have a `CommandArgument` property

you should go the custom way with `TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="DownButton" runat="server" CommandName="Down" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>' Text="Down"> </asp:Button>
        <asp:Button ID="UpButton" runat="server" CommandName="Up" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>' Text="Up"> </asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```